# NoMethodError in PostsController#create following the getting started guide

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a Rails newbie and therefore I am following the getting started guide, available here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html and here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html but I can't get the point 5.6 / 5.7 to work.

This is my controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def new
    end

    def show
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create
      @post = Post.new(post_params)

      @post.save
      redirect_to @post
    end

    private
    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
    end

end
```

and this is my form:

```
<%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :title %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.label :text %> <br>
        <%= f.text_area :text %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

This is the routes.rb

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
  get "welcome/index"

  root 'welcome#index'

  resource :posts

end
```

but when I submit it, I get this error:

`NoMethodError in PostsController#create
undefined method post_url' for #<PostsController:0x007f733c415418>` with the extract source highlighting the line `redirect_to @post`. 
What am I doing wrong? I have ruby 1.9.3 and rails 4.0.0

Comment: post your complete post controller

Comment: Also post your `routes.rb`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your `routes.rb` I see you've

```
resource :posts
```

I believe, it should be:

```
resources :posts
```

Comment: +1 for noticing this.  Also more info here for the OP: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resource

Comment: I see, I didn't know about this. But The doc you've followed asked to use `resources :posts` in http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running

Comment: I know this was a while ago, but i was stuck on this for an hour & was about to give up RoR lol. Thank you so much for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You might have missed to add the Post part in your routes. Try running rake routes and see what results you get on this :

> rake routes | grep post

if you have mentioned post in your routes then may be you are using the wrong path here.

Comment: I get        posts POST   /posts(.:format)         posts#create
    new_posts GET    /posts/new(.:format)     posts#new
   edit_posts GET    /posts/edit(.:format)    posts#edit
              GET    /posts(.:format)         posts#show
              PATCH  /posts(.:format)         posts#update
              PUT    /posts(.:format)         posts#update
              DELETE /posts(.:format)         posts#destroy

Comment: and you said u getting the error on `redirect_to @post` line ??

Comment: Yes that's right, I get highlighted the line `redirect_to @post`

Comment: instead try for `redirect_to new_post_path(@post)`

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the following line to your `config/routes.rb`?

```
resources :posts
```

Comment: Yes is present in the routes.rb file as in my question

Comment: Did you restart your server, after adding this line?

Comment: No I didn't is not mentioned in the guide, and however didn't fix my problem